# No resource 'posts' Ember App

Tags: ember.js

I'm moving over from Backbone to Ember, and to start to get the swing of things I'm trying to make a Blog App.

I get the error --

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The attempt to link-to route 'posts' failed. The router did not find 'posts' in its possible routes: 'loading', 'error', 'index', 'application'
```

This is what I have so far --

```
Blog.Router.map = function() {
  this.resource('posts');
}

Blog.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.get('store').findAll('post')
  }
})

Blog.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is a function, not a property you set.

```
Blog.Router.map( function() {
  this.resource('posts');
});
```